# Singleemail class Font Size change to 11

Tags: email, html, apex-email-service, font

I have below statement to trigger mails from apex class. But here though I put size as 11, It sends mail with size 8.5.

Can someone let me know , how to achieve desired output?

code:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11">'+body+'</p>' );
```

By default it's making size 12.

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on the email client that you are sending the email to, but the first two things I would try are:

1.Make the font-size important:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px !important;">'+body+'</p>' );
```

2.Use the (deprecated) font tag:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<font face="Calibri" size="3">'+body+'</font>');
```

Note that with the `<font>` tag, you won't be able to pick `11px` for the font size. If the difference between 11 and 12 px is too much, this option might not give you enough control to be useful.

---

Two other things that might be worth trying:

3.Use a span tag instead of a p:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<span style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px;">'+body+'</span>');
```

4.Use *internal* instead of *inline* styling:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<style>.myStyle{font-family:Calibri;font-size: 11px;}</style><span class="myStyle" >'+body+'</span>');
```

Comment: Still it get's defaulted to 12 size. I followed your first approach.